# c# change x axis min and max value

Tags: c#

I draw bars, and I want to change the values in x-axis. I have the following code. In the x-axis should be shown values between 450 and 1450, instead of the array`s index. What shoud I do?

```
int[] Values;
Series barSeries = new Series();
barSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
Values = model.calculateNNmed(name);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                barSeries.Points.Add(Values[i]);
            }
            chart1.Series.Add(barSeries);
```

Comment: As user3787557 says you need the AddXY method or your DataPoints won't have valid, different and numeirc x-values. Do have a look at the x-values in the debugger! Very instructive..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
Point[] Values;
```

And then,

```
barSeries.Points.AddXY(Values[i].X, Values[i].Y);
```

Obviously, `model.calculateNNmed(name);` has to be updated accordingly to populate x-axis between 450 and 1450.